# Add borders to SVG path d3 javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I want to have my svg paths (lines) have borders such that outlines are black, but the inside is another color. Line code:

```
self.lineFunction = function(dat) {
  var self = this
  var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('linear');

  var data = dat.map(function(d) {
    return [self.xScale(d[0]), self.yScale(d[1].mean)];
  });

  return line(data);
}

self.lines = self.svg.selectAll('.line')
  .data(d3.keys(self.data), function(d) {return d})
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', function(d) {return self.lineFunction(self.data[d])})
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .style('stroke', 'blue')
  .style('stroke-width', '2')
  .style('fill', 'none');
```

Comment: You can't do this with a single line, but you could use a `path` element instead.

Comment: I see what you're saying @LarsKotthoff -- is there a way to convert my lineFunction code into a path generator that I can then add a border to?

Comment: You could take the area generator, use your actual y coordinate for y0 and for y1 take the actual + a margin. Similar for x.

Comment: I think this is a more elegant approach than 2 lines -- I'd rather mark this as the answer if you'd like to make it one @LarsKotthoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by replacing the line with a `path`. For this, you can use D3's area generator. It requires two coordinates for each "point", but you can do this by passing in the actual coordinate to `x0` and the actual plus a margin to `x1` (and similarly for y). This margin will determine the "thickness" of the line. You can set fill/stroke as usual for the path.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: E.g. `d3.svg.area().y0(function(d) { return d.value; }).y1(function(d) { return d.value + 10; })`

Answer (score 10):

A forward-looking answer: if SVG2 was supported you could use the [`paint-order`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#PaintOrderProperty) property (assuming the fill is opaque):

```
.pathWithBorder {
  paint-order: stroke fill;
  stroke-width: 1.8;
  stroke: black;
  fill: blue;
}
```

Then there's no need to duplicate the `path` element, and the stroke will only be visible outside the shape.

Answer (score 9):

You have to create a slightly thinner line along the same path:

```
inner = self.svg
  .selectAll('.inner')
  .data(d3.keys(self.data), function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append('path')
  .attr('d', function(d) {return self.lineFunction(self.data[d])})
  .attr('class', 'inner')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', '1.8')
  .style('fill', 'none');
```

This means you have two lines on top on one another, the lower one slightly protruding from the other, giving the impression of a border.

Comment: Makes sense -- I was just hoping there was a way to do it with css as to not recreate lines.  Thanks.